# Resizing an ASP.Net image to scale in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, image-resizing

I am working on a Visual Studio master page, and trying to add the company logo.

I have imported the JPEG into my project, added an `Image` control and have set the `ImageUrl` property to my JPEG.

The problem is my image is massive! I am trying to resize it to scale, by holding down shift (which works in other MS products) but it's not working properly, and when trying to resize manually, I just can't get it to look right.

So my question is, how do I resize an image to scale in ASP.Net using Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: How about using e.g. [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) to resize your image?

Comment: I guess I could do that. It's just a pain when in Microsoft Word I can hold down shift and drag to do this, but I can't in Visual Studio!

Comment: I've heard rumours that Angry Birds can make you throw little birds on green pigs, and that you cannot do that in Visual Studio!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to change the dimensions of an image in Visual Studio.

Changing the dimensions of the image will just make the image appear smaller; it won't actually *resample* it and *reduce its size* in bytes. For both these reasons, take the extra minute or two to use another program to properly resize the image.

- Resampling: smooths the image according to an algorithm and properly handles things like edges
- Reducing size in bytes: this one is obvious. Your post is tagged with ASP.Net; you don't want a "massize" image being sent over the network.

Comment: I guess I didn't think about it from that angle, that is what I will do

Comment: Cool. Paint.Net is easy to use as @Uwe Keim mentioned, and Adobe always has a fully functional 30 day trial of Photoshop.

Comment: I'm marking this as the best answer but taking Rain's comments into account as well, ASP.Net is all new territory for me! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Visual studio is not for image scaling. You can scale the image on design view. After spefying image url for image you can re-size it as you do in powerpoint. But this is not a good practice as this will add height and width tag with specific value in your html for image.
So re-size the image using any tool as per your need and use it as this will make the page lighter.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the designer-generated width/height styles...definitely undesirable to have in your markup.